# Are there any extra steps I can take to prevent noise on the output of this circuit?

Tags: noise, boost, usb-c, switching-regulator, bridge-rectifier

I made a rectifier/boost converter PCB board in order to power a USB type-C charge module. The USB charge module will solder into the output posts on top of my board. And, since the charge module doesn't have any screw holes, the Type-C socket on the charge module will also be soldered to the exposed ground that you can see in the 3D view. I did this for extra security/strength.

Here's the problem: After several tests, I noticed that the USB charge module operates inconsistently when my board is powered by the wind turbine, and doesn't always charge. Meanwhile, this problem never happens when it's powered by a regulated DC power supply. I've checked the Turbine for proper output, and it provides more than enough power. The funny thing is that the power indicating LED on the charge module stays on the whole time.

I plan on running it on my oscilloscope this weekend, just haven't had a chance yet. In the mean time, I believe this charging issue is related to noise, and wanted to explore ways to reduce it.

My PCB board receives 3-phase AC from a wind turbine, rectifies it, and then steps it up to 18V through use of a TPS61178 DC to DC boost converter.

I added 3 560uF caps to smooth the rectified DC before it reaches everything else, and then another 10uF cap next to the VIN pin of the TPS61178.

Since the USB charge module has it's own DC to DC step-down converter built into it, I don't want the output noise from the boost converter in my PCB board to interfere with it.

Although the space on my board is limited, what are some extra steps I can take to eliminate noise at the output posts? I've read that splitting ground planes may help sometime, but I am unsure where exactly to split them. Would it be a good idea to isolate the Type-C socket pad from the rest of the ground?

PS: The reason the 3 input holes are in the middle of the board is because I needed room to solder the wind turbine wires to them with the USB charge module already installed/in place.

PCB Board Circuit Diagram:
[image: PCB Board Circuit Diagram]

Top View of the PCB Board Schematic (The empty space to the left is where the USB charge module will solder to):
[image: Top View of the PCB Board Schematic, The empty space to the left is where the USB charge module will solder to]

Bottom View of the PCB Board Schematic:
[image]

Top 3D View:
[image: Top 3D View]

Bottom 3d View:
[image]

The below two photos show what the USB charge module looks like when soldered to a similarly sized PCB board:
[image: USB Charge Module Side View]
[image: USB Charge Module Front View]

Comment: What is the AC frequency range of the turbine?

Comment: @Jens it varies anywhere from zero when there is no wind to around 1400Hz on a very-very windy day. It's also 3 Phase.